# Problem with .BAT script on imagemagick 7.0.8-25 creating LOG of files converted and TIMESTAMPS

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, mogrify

I'm working on a script that finds thousands of image files even in subfolders, (I have different types of mogrify sentences, for the different types) is supposed to create a `.log` file and insert everything there, included the current date and time.

So that's my problem, I can't make it work and I'll try a lot of things for do it, and I read literally all topics about that, but I can't find my error, and the debugger doesn't says nothing to me.

My batch file is:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LOGFILE=comprimir.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B
:LOG
FOR /r "C:\imagemagick\image" %a in (*.jpg) do
mogrify -quality 90 -interlace PLANE -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -compress 
JPEG2000 -colorspace RGB "%~a"
ECHO %DATE% %TIME%
```

But something is wrong, when I'll try to execute I get this error:

> "Is not expected in this moment"

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Double your `%` as `%%a` and `%%~a` we use `%%` in batch and single `%` on cmdline.

Comment: Hmmm... you are looping in all subfolders; you should use `%%~fA` I think or that is an incorrect syntax?

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window to find out the correct syntax...

Comment: mogrify is best suited to process all images in a directory. You can loop over multiple directories and have mogrify process all images of a given format or all images, if you want. If you are processing one image at a time via a loop, then use convert on IM 6 or magick on IM 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside a batch file, you should use `%%A` instead of `%A` you use. Also, where are your parenthesis?

Another problem, is that you are in a code block (`for` loop) and you are using `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` **without** [delayed](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) [expansion](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php). This won't work.

So, I would suggest:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "logfile=comprimir.log"
(call :log)>%logfile%
exit /B

:log
for /R "C:\imagemagick\image" %%A in (*.jpg) do (
    mogrify -quality 90 -interlace PLANE -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -compress JPEG2000 -colorspace RGB "%%~A"
    echo !date! !time!
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly. I only miss one thing for make it more visual; to see the code at the same time at console, meanwhile is writing the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from cmdline, we use `%` but inside of a batch file, we need to double up on them `%%`. You also do not have to call the label, you can pipe to log directly in one go.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "log=comprimir.log"
(for /r "C:\imagemagick\image" %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    mogrify -quality 90 -interlace PLANE -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -compress JPEG2000 -colorspace RGB "%%~a"
    echo !date! !time!
 )
)>>%log%
```